# PDFs with same file name do not appear chronologically in Google's search results

Tags: google, pdf, versioning

I have PDFs which are being updated occasionally. 
The problem is, I want to make the older versions appear in Google's search results , preferably chronologically. 
The current version should appear on the top. 
Which is currently not the case: the older ones are on the top position, followed by the newer ones.

Is the a way to let google favor the newer version?

[image: screenshot of current search result]

(current search result: older version is on the top, followed by the newer version)

Comment: do you really need the old file in index? i would deindex it simultanly with publishing/indexing the new one - the previous one becomes no longer up to date

Comment: I agree with [Evgeniy](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/users/43910/evgeniy).   Can you redirect the old PDFs to the most recent version, or use a [rel canonical link header](https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/139066?hl=en) to point Google to the most recent version?